# Ubuntu 22.04: Monitor screen no signal detected via HDMI

Tags: 22.04, dell, hdmi, monitor

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on my new Dell laptop. When I tried to connect with a monitor screen, the second screen failed to detect my Dell laptop but is OK to detect my Macbook. I'm new to linux os and I almost tried all the method I could found but non of them works.

When I run the command

```
lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
```

The result output is:

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 7480 (rev c7)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0bff
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
--
0b:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 164e (rev d9)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0bff
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
```

So seems like my new Dell laptop has two AMD GPU? Anyway I followed some suggestions to adjust the drivers and found no additional drivers. I run the command `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` and no output, and the command `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` output is "All the available drivers are already installed."

I also did upgrade and update, but that also didn't work. Power off and restarted many times still nothing change...

Please let me know if you have any idea or any information you need me to provide. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

No one answered me so I'm going to answer myself. After days of trying we finally find the way:

1. Download GPU driver from their website (in this case is AMD driver)
2. Install driver (`amdgpu-install`)
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
5. Turn off secure boot
6. Go to Software & Updates - Other software - Select amdgpu/.../ main (Source Code) and amdgpu/.../ proprietary
7. Reboot computer